# Session data works in local server, not in server - Django

Tags: python, django, django-sessions

I have a Django app which uses cookie session to pass data from one to another template/functions.

The problem that I face is that while setting the cookie with either file based, DB based it worked in local perfectly, but while I try set the same session in Digital Ocean development server, it failed for some unknown reason.

Here are file which transaction with session

settings.py

Attempt 1:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies"
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = "user_session"
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
```

Attempt 2:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.file'
SESSION_FILE_PATH = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "session")
```

views.py

```
def pre_login(request):
    request.session['pre_login'] = data
    ....

def index(request):
    user_data = request.session['pre_login']
    ....
```

While checking the cookie session in browser, it creates a sessionid for Localhost.
But when checking session for the same code, there is nothing for my development server.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the value in the request. When you try to get it in another view you're out of scope.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-out-of-views

Comment: Okay, the document makes sense. But Iam little confused, if you may help me to understand. Since it works on local system, so does it like the session values are stored somewhere in the interpreter's memory? Or how does it work?

Comment: Does your repo available to check the code? Are you using the same database in both environments?

Comment: Repo is restricted actually. I can share a few more snippet to understand. And yes both use the same database.